# How can I turn my CentOS laptop into a wireless signal repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, unix, centos, centos-6

So, I have a laptop with CentOS 6.9 (i686 arch), I need to receive the internet signal through the wi-fi adapter and repeat it to the ethernet cable, how can I do this? Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wlan0 may be connected to a dedicated DSL / ADSL / WAN / Cable router.
but you probably want it set with a static IP.

---

This answer uses these addresses as an example.

- WAN ISP Subnet = `192.168.1.0/24`
- WAN ISP Router = `192.168.1.1/24`

WLAN0 interface statically assigned a number in the `192.168.1.0` subnet

Ethernet interface statically assigned a number in the `10.10.10.0/24` subnet
(Eth0 - `10.10.10.254/24`)

---

### Step # 1: Enable Packet Forwarding

Login as the root user.
Open /etc/sysctl.conf file

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

### Add the following line to enable packet forwarding:

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1
```

**Save** and **close** the file.

### Restart networking:

```
service network restart
```

### Step # 2: Enable IP masquerading

You need to setup Network Address Translation (NAT) or Network Masquerading. In short, IP masquerading/NAT is used to share the internet connection.

### Share internet connection

To share network connection via `eth0`, enter the following rule at command prompt

```
service iptables stop
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

Open Windows / Mac / Linux computer networking GUI tool and point default gateway to the interface ip address that we will be sharing, (10.10.10.254/24 ). You also need to setup DNS IP such as `208.67.222.222` or `8.8.8.8` etc.

You should now able to ping or browse the internet:

```
ping 202.54.1.20
ping google.com
```

Automated shell Script found [here](http://www.nesociety.org/tutorials/linux-centos/how-to-share-internet-connectivity-by-enabling-ip-fowarding-in-centos/) to setup basic Linux network sharing:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Created by nixCraft - www.cyberciti.biz
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
MOD="/sbin/modprobe"

# set wan interface such as eth1 or ppp0
SHARE_IF="eth0"

# clean old fw
echo "Clearing old firewall rules..."
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Get some kernel modules
echo "Loading kernel modules..."
$MOD ip_tables
$MOD iptable_filter
$MOD iptable_nat
$MOD ip_conntrack
$MOD ipt_MASQUERADE
$MOD ip_nat_ftp
$MOD ip_nat_irc
$MOD ip_conntrack_ftp
$MOD ip_conntrack_irc

# Clean old rules if any, rhel specific but above will take care of everything
# service iptables stop

# unlimited traffic via loopback device
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

echo "Setting ${SHARE_IF} as router interface..."
$IPT --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface ${SHARE_IF} -j MASQUERADE

# Start other custom rules
#$IPT 
# End other custom rules

echo "*** Instructions on TCP/IP On The Windows / Mac / Linux Masqueraded Client ***"
echo "1. Login to your other LAN desktop computers"
echo "2. Open network configuration GUI tool such. Under Windows XP - Click Start, click Control Panel, click Network and Internet Connections, and then click Network Connections"
echo "3. Set DNS (NS1 and NS2) to 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220"
echo "4. Select the 'Gateway' tab in the TCP/IP properties dialog."
echo "5. Enter $(ifconfig ${SHARE_IF} | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}') as the default gateway."
```

References:

- [How to share Internet connectivity by enabling IP Fowarding in CentOS](http://www.nesociety.org/tutorials/linux-centos/how-to-share-internet-connectivity-by-enabling-ip-fowarding-in-centos/)
- [Internet Connection Sharing on CentOS 7](https://www.rudraraj.net/internet-connection-sharing-ics-on-centos-7/)
- [CentOS / Redhat Linux Internet Connection Sharing](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-linux-internet-connection-sharing-howto/)